# How to share variable within two excel object?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use the variable from `ThisWorkbook` to Sheet1?

I would like to store the `Lastrow` value once my Excel file is opened. This `Lastrow` value will be use later in commandbutton. I use msgbox in commandbutton to see whether the value is share, and the msgbox show nothing.

This is from Excel object `ThisWorkbook`

```
Public Lastrow As Long

Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ActiveSheet
        Lastrow = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Application.Goto Reference:=.Range("A" & Lastrow + 1)

        MsgBox "Last row is" & Lastrow
        .Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

This is from Excel object Sheet1

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    MsgBox "Last row is" & wb.Lastrow
End Sub
```

I wanna take the value from workbook to sheet1. For example, the msgbox show 6 once Excel file open, the msgbox in commandbutton2 will show the same.

Comment: Put `Public LastRow As Long` into a module and you can use it everywhere by just using `MsgBox "Last row is" & LastRow`

Comment: You already have the answer in your question. `ThisWorkbook` is a reference to the workbook where your code resides. `ThisWorkbook.Lastrow` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in …

```
Dim wb As Workbook
MsgBox "Last row is" & wb.Lastrow
```

… `wb` is `Nothing` because you didn't set a workbook (it should throw an error). So either set a workbook:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
MsgBox "Last row is" & wb.Lastrow
```

… or just use `ThisWorkbook.Lastrow`.

I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

---

Alternatively move `Public LastRow As Long` into a **module**. This way you can use it everywhere just like `MsgBox "Last row is" & Lastrow`.